# How to download mp3 files in sequence?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using `_webClient.OpenReadAsync(myURI)` to download files, it works fine to download files. I want to download the files in sequence starting from 0-20. the 1st file should be downloaded, then the 2nd and so on. 
I am using below to download, but it's not what I am expecting.

```
foreach (string s in files)
    _webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}", selectedReciter.DownloadURL, s)));
```

The `for` loop should only continue to 2nd, 3rd and so on, if 1st file is downloaded, then 2nd, then 3rd and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening URL for reading *asynchronously*, that word has heavy meaning. What will happen is that the function won't complete when the file has began reading, but rather it will return much sooner.

What you need to do there is to `await` the result, something like this:

```
async Task DownloadAll(List<string> addresses)
{
    var wc = new WebClient();
    foreach(var address in addresses)
        await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync(address);
}
```

Don't forget to add the NuGet package: `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` first.

Answer (score 0):

Use Background file transfer to download files. Background file transfer allows you to download files also in background means when your application are deactivate or in background.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is more about Background file transfer. And [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is an example how to use background file transfer.

Comment: Thanks, this can help. Though I used WebClient, now i have to look for Background file transfer.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the non-async version of the same method that blocks execution until the OpenRead stream is complete.

Comment: There is no sync version of it.

Comment: Only in .NET 4.5, but not on Silverlight for Windows Phone. I just checked it in Visual Studio, Silverlight doesn't have synchronous versions at all thus forcing you to use asynchronous methods.

Comment: Can you not add the `).Result` to the call to force it to complete execution?

Comment: Only if you have NuGet package installed and if you use `OpenReadTaskAsync` method, the one mentioned by OP (`OpenReadAsync`) calls the specified delegate once the connection succeeds.